# search live database from textbox and display it in select element

Tags: angular

The component is finished but client is not happy. Currently, I search for products on a live database using a textbox and display the results in a select element with database id and name forming the value and display text of each select option as shown below:

[image]

The client basically wants to have a google like search (one element visible). I use the selected ID when submitting the form to the database which is mysql. Is there away a simpler way that wont require me to change a lot (admit...am being lazy).

The backend is Django which sends JSON.

Here is my current component code:

```
 eventSearchSupplier(value){
 let v=value.trim();
 if (v.length<2){return false;}

 //search here
    this.suppliersservice.searchsupplier(v).subscribe(
      data => { 
          this.suppliers = data['detail'];

          this.suppliers.unshift({'id':0,'name':'Select'});


      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

         if (err.error instanceof Error) {
             //A client-side or network error occurred.         
      this.commonfunctions.showNotificationMessage('',909,'error');
     } else {
         this.commonfunctions.showNotificationMessage(err.error.detail,err.status,'error');

     }
      }       
  );
```

}

component.html

```
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Suppliers</label>
        <input type="text" class="text-line" placeholder="Enter Name to Search" (input)="eventSearchSupplier($event.target.value)">

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>


        <select  class="form-control supplier" formControlName="provider" >
            <option *ngFor="let supplier of suppliers" value="{{supplier.id}}">{{supplier.name}}</option>

        </select>

    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean 1 element visible? of course you can simplify this by mimicking an autocomplete control. whenever a client types, a suggestions is listed down the input text.

Comment: he hates the fact that he types in the text box then had to go the combobox to select the item he wanted, which is unfriendly of course. Anyway, lemme search a suitable autocomplete solution as you suggested

Comment: of course i also hate it, not so UX friendly. Try to be a bit user oriented when doing design